# Dealing with logger classes in Guice

Tags: java, logging, dependency-injection, guice

Now I am reading [the official document of Guice.](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/BuiltInBindings)  However, I don't understand this sentence.

> Guice has a built-in binding for java.util.logging.Logger, intended to save some boilerplate. The binding automatically sets the logger's name to the name of the class into which the Logger is being injected..

In the above sentence, what do `the logger's name` and `the name of the class` indicate? 
Even under the hook, I think Guice defines the bindings in the same format like `bind().to()`.
And then doesn't Guice define like this `bind(java.util.logging.Logger).to(implementClass)` or no `toClause`.   Anyway, I can't understand the sentence of the official document.   Could anyone explain?

EDIT

```
    @Singleton
public class ConsoleTransactionLog implements TransactionLog {

  private final Logger logger;

  @Inject
  public ConsoleTransactionLog(Logger logger) {
    this.logger = logger;
  }

  public void logConnectException(UnreachableException e) {
    /* the message is logged to the "ConsoleTransacitonLog" logger */
    logger.warning("Connect exception failed, " + e.getMessage());
  }
```

Comment: Are you asking what a logger name is?

Comment: That is a part of my question.    Could you tell me what it is?

Comment: When you get a logger, you normally provide a class name for context, e.g. `Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName());`. Guice just automates that.

Comment: Now I am very clear.   So, although this is an additional question, in this case Guice uses an injection using the explicit constructor where the parameter is equal to `String`?